# InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 605: i could not fix it. can you help me?

Tags: laravel-5.3

The command used to route to that

[image]

```
return redirect()->action('GuardianAuth\LoginController@login')->withInput();
```

in LoginController[image]
in in AuthenticatesUsers[image]

Comment: As its says action not defined, can you verify the login controller namesapce & whether the login function is under the controller

Comment: In logincontroller  function **AuthenticatesUsers** is defined. the AuthenticatesUsers function contains the login function.

Comment: Did you add the action in `routes/web.php` ?

Comment: Yes '//Guardian Login
Route::get('guardian/login', 'GuardianAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('guardian/login', 'GuardianAuth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('guardian/logout', 'GuardianAuth\LoginController@logout');'

Comment: Can you try this `redirect()->action('GuardianAuth\LoginController@login', $request);`. Guessing this because `login` function has `request` parameter. Hope `$request` is available whereever you are calling it.

Comment: If above doesn't work try `redirect()->action('GuardianAuth\LoginController@login', [$request]);`. Trying to sent as array

Comment: Run this command `php artisan routes` & double check whether routes are defined properly. Look out for typing mistakes, something my common  mistake :)

Comment: Sorry I'm out of guesses for today, hope someone will help you.

Comment: Did you fix it?